# Howto migrate Outlook 2007 settings between PCs?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I have an Outlook 2007 install on Windows XP, and would like to migrate to a Windows 7 workstation.  I've found there's a Signatures folder in docs and settings\name\application data\Microsoft, and there's Outlook folders in both LocalSettings and Application Data...

But is there really no easy way to move my Outlook settings from one workstation to another? I want my signature, rules, window layout, etc., all on the new PC.  Does it really all have to be done separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in File - Export for options for exporting a single file.

Generally speaking, though, you'll want to copy the various Outlook user data directories and paste them in place on the new system.

The Local Settings file will be most important as it will contain any email messages, account settings, calendars, and the like.

The other thing to try is the Files And Settings Transfer Wizard. This will, by default, create a single archive file with all your personal directory and settings information. You can choose what to collect and move as well, if you really only need the Outlook info.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to sync some of that stuff would be to use [**Windows Live Mesh 2011**](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh-sync-program-settings-using?os=other).  Everything else is kept on the Exchange server, so does not need syncing unless, of course, you are not using Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Usually just exporting the mailbox(es) to a PST and then importing it into the new Outlook will get MOST information (mail, contacts, appointments, etc.).  But things like account settings, macros, RPC over HTTP proxy settings, etc. probably won't get moved.

Since you're going to Windows 7 from XP you should try the [W.E.T.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer) (Windows Easy Transfer) wizard instead of XP's F.A.S.T. (Files And Settings Transfer).

You can get the XP-side WET client from MS, [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2b6f1631-973a-45c7-a4ec-4928fa173266).  Windows 7 has WET built in for importing.